# XSLT: Mapping multiple elements in source xsd to a single element in target XSD

Tags: xslt, xsd

I have a requirement to map multiple elements in a source XSD to a single element in target XSD using XSLT transformation. let me explain with an example:
Source XSD will be like below

```
<xsd:element name="SDQ">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="C1" type="xsd:string" />
   <xsd:element name="C2" type="xsd:string" />
   <xsd:element name="C3" type="xsd:string" />
  . . and so on
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Target XSD will be:

```
<xsd:element name="StoreNumber">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="C1" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Now the problem is I need to map/generate XML for each element in the source to the only element in the Target. 
I tried using "choose", "For each" but its not working.
So please let me know if we have any solution to achieve the above functionality.

Thanks In Advance.

Sample Input and expected Output:
Input XML:

```
<Segment-SDQ> <Element-67>008</Element-67> <Element-67_1>018</Element-67_1> <Element-67_2>027</Element-67_2> <Element-67_3>044</Element-67_3> </Segment-SDQ>
```

Required output:

```
<StoreNumber> <c1>008</c1> <c1>018</c1> <c1>027</c1> </StoreNumber>
```

Comment: Please post a (small) example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: Hi michael.hor257k, 
Input: 
<Segment-SDQ>
<Element-67>008</Element-67>
<Element-67_1>018</Element-67_1>
<Element-67_2>027</Element-67_2>
<Element-67_3>044</Element-67_3>
</Segment-SDQ> 
Required output: 
<StoreNumber> 
<c1>008</c1>
<c1>018</c1> 
<c1>027</c1> 
</StoreNumber>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments- edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your example input:

**XML**

```
<Segment-SDQ>
   <Element-67>008</Element-67>
   <Element-67_1>018</Element-67_1>
   <Element-67_2>027</Element-67_2>
   <Element-67_3>044</Element-67_3>
</Segment-SDQ>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Segment-SDQ">
    <StoreNumber>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <c1>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </c1>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </StoreNumber>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StoreNumber>
   <c1>008</c1>
   <c1>018</c1>
   <c1>027</c1>
   <c1>044</c1>
</StoreNumber>
```

Note that neither your input nor your output conform to the XSDs shown in your question.